# Capistrano cap deploy:setup does not create any files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, svn, capistrano

I don't get any error message while I execute `cap deploy:setup`. It attempts to create folder `/myapp` as `mkdir -p /home/user/apps/myapp`, and also other folders (releases, shared). There is no permission issue as I can execute `mkdir -p /home/user/apps/myapp` without any error in terminal. Furthermore, `cap deploy:check` gives `You appear to have all necessary dependencies installed` message. Am I supposed to have those folders created with `cap deploy:setup`? If so, why am I not getting any error message and also the folders created?

Here's my config/deploy.rb file:

```
set :application, "myapp"
set :location, "myserver"
set :domain, "apps.mydomain.com"
set :user, "app_admin"

set :repository,  "svn+ssh://app_admin@192.168.XXX.XXX/home/svn/myapp"
set :svn_username, "svn_admin"
set :svn_password, "password"
set :use_sudo, false
set :scm, :subversion
default_run_options[:pty] = true

role :web, location                          
role :app, location                        
role :db,  location, :primary => true 

set :deploy_to, "/home/app_admin/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :checkout
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

namespace :deploy do
  task :start, :roles => :app do
    run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end
  task :stop, :roles => :app do
    #do nothing
  end
  desc "Restart Application"
  task :restart, :roles => :app do
    run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end
end
```

Comment: What are the contents of your config/deploy.rb?

Comment: @Salil I've added the contents of my config/deploy.rb. Thanks!

Comment: It's surprising that capistrano does not generate any errors. Are you sure there is no output generated? Can you do "ssh -q app_admin@myserver exit" and make sure that shell variable #? is 0? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405324/how-to-create-a-bash-script-to-check-the-ssh-connection)

Comment: @ Salil Finally, I get it working but the deployment is not in the public server (although I am running the `cap deploy:setup` command from the same server). It is deploying in the machine with repo SVN (i.e. 192.168.XXX.XXX). Any suggestion?

Answer (score -8):

What capistrano version? What OS?
I have problems with Capistrano in Ubuntu - try Windows! I've usually found that Windows is the best server platform. Except for the infrequent crashes, windows server is very powerful.