# BASH SSH Redirect on Fail

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a BASH script that logs in to multiple servers and runs a series of commands. Occasionally I'll have instances where a server is unavailable (regular maintenance, etc). How can I exit out of the SSH session cleanly without passing an error like this?:

```
bash-3.2$ ssh myserver3
Disconnecting: Bad packet length.
```

Comment: Are you asking how you could avoid the message going to stderr?

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for `-q` option:

```
ssh -q user@host
```

And you can check the return code `$?` afterwards.

From [`man bash`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh%201):

> **-q**
>
> Quiet mode.  Causes all warning and diagnostic messages to be
>   suppressed

You can find more info about this topic in [How to create a bash script to check the SSH connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1405324/1983854).