# SSH always exits with code 0. How to check if connection succeeded?

Tags: ssh, sh

I am trying to check that an SSH connection succeeds (while running a script).

I am trying to use the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405324/how-to-create-a-bash-script-to-check-the-ssh-connection), but the unsuccessful connection returns an error code of 0.

```
$ ssh -q user@downhost exit
$ echo $?
0
```

I have tried a variety of invalid `ssh` commands but they all return a `0` return code; making it hard to check for failure.

I feel I must be doing something  wrong, but can't work it out.  Is there some setting that I have changed maybe?

I am running CentOS 7, with the following SSH version:

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.6.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
```

Comment: Did you try the other answers, for example running `ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=5 user@host echo ok 2>&1` ? which will `ok` on successful login.

Comment: `ssh -q user@downhost exit` Why are you expecting this command to fail? Do you understand that in the other question, "downhost" is supposed to represent a host that's not accessible at the time?

Comment: @Inian, I could possibly hack something together from that answer (running in a subshell maybe?), but I want this to be the condition of an ``if`` statement, so the return code seemed the place to look.

Comment: @Kenster. I have tried it with an uncontactable IP address, a non-existent hostname and a hostname that fails host key checking.  I remain confused.  I was expecting the command to fail unless it successfully connected.

Answer (score -1):

I remain confused as to why the example is failing, but the following seems to be working for me.

```
can_connect_ssh()
{
    HOST=$1
    ssh -q -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=5 $HOST echo connection_success | \
       grep connection_success &> /dev/null
}
```

Called as:

```
if can_connect_ssh <hostname>; then
    echo "Successful Connection"
else
    echo "Failed Connection"
fi
```

Comment: I doubt very much that works for you. I think you meant to omit the `return` keyword from `can_connect_ssh`.