# how many possible error message can response if ssh disconnected?

Tags: ssh

I want check ssh session disconnect at sometime in a program.
In the stage, I'm check response stream match the disconnect template to decide connection is closed.The template could be:
`Timeout, server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx not responding.` and `packet_write_wait: Connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Broken pipe`

Is there others message could be print?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a bash script to check the SSH connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405324/how-to-create-a-bash-script-to-check-the-ssh-connection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unreliable to parse `ssh` output as it's flavor, locale and version-specific. It can also recite system error messages ("Broken pipe" in your case) which are, naturally, OS-specific.

Instead, check for [exit status `255`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh).